# serial data transfer using device node

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, termios

I need to communicate over my serial Port. I have written a c code to open the devices for tx & rx and configure the settings, write and read the data. First time when I execute the code, I'm able to read and write data. But when I try it second time, I'm unable to receive or transmit data. Can sometime help me to know what the reason for that will be. I have closed the files that are opened.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<termios.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

#define buff_size 256

 int main()
{
        int tx_fd,rx_fd;
        struct termios option1,option2;
        int byte_write,byte_read;
        char buffer[buff_size];

        printf("test\n");

        tx_fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB2",O_RDWR);
        printf("tx port is opened\n");
        if(tx_fd < 0)
        {
                perror("error opening transmitter uart port");
                return 1;
        }

        rx_fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDWR);
        printf("rx port opened\n");
        if(rx_fd < 0)
        {
                perror("error opening receiver uart port");
                close(tx_fd);
                return 1;
        }

        //configuration setting
        ////baud rate oof input and output is set to 9600;
        cfsetospeed(&option2,B9600);
        cfsetispeed(&option1,B9600);

        ////
        option1.c_cflag = CS8;
        option2.c_cflag = CS8;


        option1.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
        option2.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
        option1.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
 tcflush(tx_fd,TCIFLUSH);
        tcflush(rx_fd,TCOFLUSH);

        // Apply receiver (RX) settings
    if (tcsetattr(rx_fd, TCSANOW, &option2) < 0) {
        perror("Error setting receiver attributes");
        close(tx_fd);
        close(rx_fd);
        return 1; // Handle the error and exit
    }
    
tcsetattr(tx_fd,TCSANOW,&option1);
    tcsetattr(rx_fd,TCSANOW,&option2);

        char data[] = "hello! \n";
        byte_write = write(tx_fd,data,sizeof(data));
        printf("write %d bytes to receiver\n",byte_write);


        if(byte_write < 0)
        {
                perror("Error in writing data\n");
                close(tx_fd);
                close(rx_fd);
                return 1;
        }

        usleep(10000);

        byte_read = read(rx_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
        if(byte_read < 0)
        {
                perror("error in reading data\n");
                close(tx_fd);
                close(rx_fd);
                return 1;
        }

        buffer[byte_read] = '\0';
        printf("read %d bytes from transmitter\n",byte_read);
        printf("Received: %s \n",buffer);

        if( close(rx_fd) < 0)
        {  perror("there is a error in closing rx");
        }
        if( close(tx_fd) < 0)
        {
                perror("there is a error in closing tx");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

this is the code that I have tried. I found that I'm having an issue with a particular serial port to open the file while executing for the second time. But still can't understand what the issue is. The code stands in a place where it can't be open, but the error message is also not executed.

Comment: `option1` and `option2` have not been fully initialized and may contain junk. It's often a good idea to read the existing termios settings with `tcgetattr()` before modifying them.

Comment: Also, the `tcsetattr()` calls for the tx side are commented out.

Comment: It looks like you have pretty good error handling code but you forgot to post the expected output and the actual output of your program when you run it the second time.  Also, what kind of devices are you reading and writing from?  Can you simplify your code so it only opens one serial port and still reproduces the problem?

Comment: I had tried all these ways but still can't open the file in the second execution.

Comment: I found that I'm having an issue with a particular serial port to open the file while executing for the second time. But still can't understand what the issue is. The code stands in a place where it can't be open, but the error message is also not executed.

Comment: "*But still can't understand what the issue is.*" -- You're not helping yourself by ignoring @IanAbbott 's first comment. Your code uses two (2) uninitialized structures, so you can expect unreliable program execution. You're lucky that it seems to work even the first time. Study [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html) as well as  [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](https://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/serial/serial.pdf)

Comment: The "*device node*"s that your program uses are for serial terminals, rather than  "*serial port*"s.  The difference is that there are additional functional layers, such as a line discipline, that can provide additional buffering and processing of the data. Your program neglects to perform any termios configuration (other than baudrate and framing), and therefore leaves it to chance. You can expect unreliable program execution.

Answer (score 1):

If the `open()` call is blocked when the executable is run the second time, it is probably because the `CLOCAL` flag was cleared in the `struct termios` `c_cflag` member when the executable was run the first time. That causes a blocking `open()` call to wait for the Carrier Detect (a.k.a. CD, Data Carrier Detect, DCD) signal to be asserted on the serial line.

`open()` can be called in nonblocking mode by setting the `O_NONBLOCK` flag in the second parameter. That will make `open()` return immediately without waiting for the CD signal, allowing you to change the termios settings.  However, the read and write operations will also be in nonblocking mode. To restore blocking mode, you can use the `fcntl()` `F_SETFL` command to clear the `O_NONBLOCK` flag after opening:

```
        rx_fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
        if(rx_fd < 0)
        {
                perror("error opening receiver uart port");
                close(tx_fd);
                return 1;
        }
        // get file control flags for receiver
        int rx_flg = fcntl(rx_fd, F_GETFL);
        if (rx_flg == -1)
        {
                perror("error getting receiver file flags");
                close(rx_fd);
                close(tx_fd);
                return 1;
        }
        // disable nonblocking mode for receiver file
        rx_flg &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
        if (fcntl(rx_fd, F_SETFL, rx_flg) == -1)
        {
                perror("error disabling nonblocking mode on receiver");
                close(rx_fd);
                close(tx_fd);
                return 1;
        }
```

The nonblocking open with blocking restored after the open could be factored out into a function that can also be used to open the other TTY:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int tty_open(const char *pathname, int flags)
{
    int fd;
    int save_errno;

    /* Open in nonblocking mode. */
    fd = open(pathname, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    save_errno = errno;
    if (fd != -1 && (flags & O_NONBLOCK) == 0)
    {
        /* Restore originally requested blocking mode. */
        if (fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) == -1)
        {
            save_errno = errno;
            close(fd);
            fd = -1;
        }
    }
    errno = save_errno;
    return fd;
}
```

That could be called like this:

```
        rx_fd = tty_open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDWR);
```

You should also either fully initialize the `struct termios` objects passed to `tcsetattr()`, or use `tcgetattr()` to read the existing settings into the `struct termios` objects before modifying the settings. Your current code only initializes the `c_cflag` members of `option1` and `option2`. The other members contain indeterminate values, which will either cause the `tcsetattr()` calls to return an error, or indeterminate termios settings to be applied to the TTY, or some other *undefined behavior* to occur.